# Blinking text in initramfs

Tags: grub, vga, console

I use

```
echo -e "\x1b[01;05;32m    ***  \x1b[0m"
```

for print blinking stars, and all works fine.

But when I try change resolution by kernel parameter

```
vga=0x0307
```

and\or grub options

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1280x1024
```

text not blinking, and I see green stars on gray background.

So I need save blinking mode and change resolution too.

P.S. And how figure out current mode of current console?